# How to use 2 different Tomcat servers in IntelliJ 10.5?

Tags: tomcat, intellij-idea

I am using IntelliJ 10.5

I want to deploy 2 different war files, they will work on different ports. I tried everything I could but couldn't make it work.

Any help?

( I want 2 Tomcat servers on 2 different ports )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define 2 different Tomcat servers in IDEA `Settings` | `Application Servers`, one of them needs ports changed in `config/server.xml` so that you can start 2 copies at the same time. In IDEA create 2 Tomcat Run/Debug configurations that will use different servers and different artifacts for deployment.

Note that you need to change not only the HTTP port, but also the `shutdown` port.